# Pandas: Total run time of a trial

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have created a pandas sheet where I can import a .csv file and run it to collect information about trials I am doing.

I want to add a "run time" feature that will let me know how long the test went on for.

```
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f' , errors = 'coerce')
```

I Have this format of date/time, the sheets are usually 15,000 rows long, what would be the best way to calculate the total runtime in hours? I wanted to find the min time and the max time and simply calculate the difference but I have gotten a ton of errors when doing this.

```
start = df[df['Date/Time']].min()
end = df[df['Date/Time']].max()
```

This is the error I get when trying this way:

> KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2021-10-01 04:49:45.625000',
> '2021-10-01 04:49:45.750000',\n               '2021-10-01
> 04:49:45.875000',                        'NaT',\n
> '2021-10-01 04:49:46.125000', '2021-10-01 04:49:46.250000',\n
> '2021-10-01 04:49:46.375000', '2021-10-01 04:49:46.500000',\n
> '2021-10-01 04:49:46.625000', '2021-10-01 04:49:46.750000',\n
> ...\n                                      'NaT', '2021-10-01
> 21:15:24.125000',\n               '2021-10-01 21:15:24.250000',
> '2021-10-01 21:15:24.375000',\n               '2021-10-01
> 21:15:24.500000', '2021-10-01 21:15:24.625000',\n
> '2021-10-01 21:15:24.750000', '2021-10-01 21:15:24.875000',\n
> 'NaT', '2021-10-01 21:15:25.125000'],\n
> dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=12405, freq=None)] are in the
> [columns]")

Comment: Just do `df['Date/Time'].min()` etc

Comment: Wow I am dumb... thank you

Comment: happens to the best of us